# PDO query returns multiple arrays. How to uniquely identify them?

Tags: mysql, pdo

This query returns 13 individual arrays:

```
$array  = array($pgff_id, $pgfm_id, $pgmf_id, $pgmm_id, $mgff_id, $mgfm_id, $mgmf_id, $mgmm_id, $pgf_id, $pgm_id, $mgf_id, $mgm_id, $fid, $mid);

foreach($array as $id) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT birth_year, death_year FROM index WHERE id = ?");
  $stmt->execute([$id]);
  $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

print_r shows that they look like this:

```
Array ([birth_year] => 1750 [death_year] => 1824) 
Array ([birth_year] => 1770 [death_year] => 1836) 
... etc
```

Is it possible to assign a number or name to these individual arrays? The results are not useful without a way to identify them.

I tried doing it like shown below. This way does number the arrays but orders the results as they are found in the table. I really need the results ordered as they are in $array (which the first method does manage).

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT birth_year, death_year FROM index WHERE id IN ($in)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: A simple way would be to use `id` as an expression in the query. Like this: `SELECT id, birth_year, death_year FROM ....`. That was your queries return the `id` as an identifier.

Comment: How would one echo the information contained in, say, the 5th array? Adding `id` to the query adds another key value pair which I don't know how to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code and adding in `id` as an expression in the query would result in this:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($array));
$sql = "SELECT id, birth_year, death_year FROM index WHERE id IN ($in)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "here starts another row:<br>";
    echo "id = ".$row["id"]."<br>";
    echo "birth_year = ".$row["birth_year"]."<br>";
    echo "death_year = ".$row["death_year"]."<br>";
}
```

So, that's how you can access it.

You can rearrange the data in the rows after you've received them from the database, again by using a `foreach` loop:

```
$birth = [];
$death = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $birth[$id] = $row["birth_year"];
    $death[$id] = $row["death_year"];
}
```

Now you can access both arrays to get the birth or death year based on the `id` like this:

```
echo $birth[4]. 'and '. $death[4];
```

where `id` is `4`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm  being a pest, but I don't wish to simply echo out all rows consecutively within a `foreach`. I want to be able to "access" or "grab" specific bits of data from the query result and use that data elsewhere. For example, imagine that I wish to use the years of birth and death from the 4th and 9th arrays.  To do that each array must (?) have a unique name or number. Something like `echo $data[4]["birth_year"] ` or `echo $data[id]["birth_year"] ` is the sort of thing I think I need.

Comment: To add: this code is part of a script that creates a family tree diagram several generations deep. This means array number 4 must always, always be the data for the mother of the paternal grandmother. Similar situation with the other arrays. They have to be strictly ordered (or labelled somehow). The `IN` statement method  is essentially randomizing the order of the arrays because it sorts them by the order it finds them in the db. The first method I showed in the OP returns results in the exact order specified in the array used by the foreach loop query, but without an index number.

Comment: @Dumarest I've added a section to my answer. This is very basic stuff for PHP, perhaps it would be better to do [some simple tutorials](https://www.learn-php.org/) first, before diving in the deep end.

Comment: Perhaps `$rows = array_column($rows, null, 'id');` might be cleaner...

Comment: @Nick: Yes, that's certainly nice for advanced users, but it gives someone, who is just starting to learn how arrays work little insight, in how to manipulate them. It will probably only confuse the issue. I will therefore not include it in my answer.